# regex to match simple URLs does not work properly

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm trying to make a simple regex expression to match simple URLs (without URL parameters etc.)
it seems to work but there is still some problem..

This is my regex:

```
/(https|http|ftp):\/\/((-|[a-z0-9])+\.)+(com|org|net)\/?((-|[a-z0-9]\/?)+(-|[a-z0-9])*\.(css|js))?/ig
```

In this little list you can see what does not work properly:

```
HTTP://q-2Ud.a.q-2Ud.com/
https://q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/c ------------------------------------> NOT WORK
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/cs -----------------------------------> NOT WORK
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/css ----------------------------------> NOT WORK
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/csss ---------------------------------> NOT WORK
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/csss/css -----------------------------> NOT WORK
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/css/yuyuyu/gyygug.css
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/h/.css -------------------------------> NOT WORK
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/.css
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/k.css
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/kk.css
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/kkk.css
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/f-1.css
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/o/o.css
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/d-1/d-2/d-3/d-4/f-1.css
http://www.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.q-2Ud.com/q-2Ud/q-2Ud/q-2Ud/q-2Ud/q-2Ud.js
```

**[Demo Here](http://www.regexr.com/39kod)**

Comment: Are you aware that your regexp only match com/org/net domain name ? Don't you want an universal regexp ?

Comment: What do you mean by `NOT WORK`?

Comment: Are you looking for insight into why it doesn't catch the ones it misses? You have it set up to either end with .com, .org, or .net (with or without a slash) or some characters followed by .css (or .js). So, it misses characters after the slash that don't end with .css, or .css without any characters preceding it. How to correct it depends on exactly what you're trying to catch vs. what you want to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

it is matching URLs with .css or .js ending.
Remove `\.(css|js)` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
/(https|http|ftp):\/\/((-|[a-z0-9])+\.)+(com|org|net)\/?\.?((-|[a-z0-9]\/?)+(-|[a-z0-9])*\/?(\.css|\.js)?)?/ig
```

This may catch all the ones that you are missing

Comment: With your code something still does not work: [UPDATED DEMO](http://www.regexr.com/39kq9)

Comment: but the updated demo shown as matches not sure why, the regex is correct, where are not working? on your browser? what browser and version do you use?

Comment: I have Chrome [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36]

Comment: @sudo-ie What is still not working is: http://example.com/.css or http://example.com/path/.css This is no good...

Comment: @sudo-ie I mean this http://www.regexr.com/39kq9 please have a look: as I have writed in this updated demo, there are still only 2 errors: there is no one address over the internet like this `http://www.some.com/.css` or this `http://www.some.com/path/.css` or this `http://www.some.com/path/path2/.js` etc...

Comment: @neoDev - Your example say's `http://www.some.com/path/path2/.js` not work. Are trying to match that or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to arrange the groups a little better while maintaining validity.
This is trimmed to capture just the main 4 parts without delimiters.

**edit**: If you don't  want to match `.js` or `.css` without a filename, use this regex ->

```
(?i)(https|http|ftp)://((?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)+(?:com|org|net))(?:/(?:([a-z0-9-]+(?:/?[a-z0-9-])*(?:\.(css|js))?))?)?
```

otherwise use this one ->

```
 # /(?i)(https|http|ftp):\/\/((?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)+(?:com|org|net))(?:\/(?:([a-z0-9-]+(?:\/?[a-z0-9-])*)\/?)?(?:\.(css|js))?)?/

 (?i)
 ( https | http | ftp )        # (1)
 ://
 (                             # (2 start)
      (?:
           [a-z0-9-]+ 
           \.
      )+

      (?: com | org | net )
 )                             # (2 end)
 (?:
      /
      (?:
           (                             # (3 start)
                [a-z0-9-]+ 
                (?:
                     /? 
                     [a-z0-9-] 
                )*
           )                             # (3 end)
           /?
      )?
      (?:
           \.
           ( css | js )                  # (4)
      )?
 )?
```

Comment: What language is that? Is it javascript?

Comment: Not a language, regex. This works in any language. The `/.../` at the top is delimited for JS. Are you getting problems with it?

Comment: I don't understand how to try it.. I've found online regex testers that provide only one line input to enter the regex, how can I test the code?

Comment: This is the raw regex: `(?i)(https|http|ftp)://((?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)+(?:com|org|net))(?:/(?:([a-z0-9-]+(?:/?[a-z0-9-])*)/?)?(?:\.(css|js))?)?`

Comment: This is the JS delimited regex: `/(?i)(https|http|ftp):\/\/((?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)+(?:com|org|net))(?:\/(?:([a-z0-9-]+(?:\/?[a-z0-9-])*)\/?)?(?:\.(css|js))?)?/`